# Does pages in an hybrid app gets converted to activities

Tags: android, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I know it might sounds generic question but i need to know something about hybrid app.
I have a hybrid app developed using cordova framework, it has multiple pages(html divs).
Now, my question is does each page gets converted into an activity when i compile it(specific to andriod).

Thanks in advance

Comment: No!. it will not complie into an activity. it runs on a webView.

Comment: A unique Activity inside a Webview

Answer (score 0):

Your app will consist of one Activity only, which consists of a webview. In this webview your html content will be loaded. You can probably tell that the page transitions of your app differs from the native Android page transitions.